# Hide and show Google line chart based on checkbox toggle toggle(Check/Uncheck)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a google line chart with 4 lines in it.

And based on checkbox toggle(Check/Uncheck) I have to Hide and show the chart lines but I got some error.

I am using [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dlaliberte/a3cgLkq6/) fiddle sample

Error screen shot

[image]

My code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
   google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMultilineChart);
   function drawMultilineChart(){
          var forGraph={
                  "201": [
                    [
                      "date",
                      "subscribers",
                      "clicks",
                      "ctr",
                      "sent"
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-11",
                      32,
                      30,
                      0.347947,
                      8622
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-12",
                      46,
                      36,
                      0.4111,
                      8757
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-13",
                      37,
                      43,
                      0.523624,
                      8212
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-14",
                      49,
                      73,
                      0.69385,
                      10521
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-15",
                      48,
                      39,
                      0.520903,
                      7487
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-16",
                      37,
                      34,
                      0.476658,
                      7133
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-17",
                      31,
                      31,
                      0.355872,
                      8711
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-18",
                      40,
                      55,
                      0.611995,
                      8987
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-19",
                      42,
                      32,
                      0.350301,
                      9135
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-20",
                      39,
                      30,
                      0.42206,
                      7108
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-21",
                      37,
                      27,
                      0.257535,
                      10484
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-22",
                      46,
                      38,
                      0.542392,
                      7006
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-23",
                      38,
                      24,
                      0.360469,
                      6658
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-24",
                      46,
                      24,
                      0.311891,
                      7695
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-25",
                      43,
                      35,
                      0.437883,
                      7993
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-26",
                      37,
                      37,
                      0.454601,
                      8139
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-27",
                      37,
                      30,
                      0.42511,
                      7057
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-28",
                      26,
                      50,
                      0.440956,
                      11339
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-29",
                      22,
                      28,
                      0.338614,
                      8269
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-30",
                      29,
                      36,
                      0.327899,
                      10979
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-31",
                      28,
                      29,
                      0.388427,
                      7466
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-08-01",
                      36,
                      20,
                      0.230123,
                      8691
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-08-02",
                      21,
                      29,
                      0.34491,
                      8408
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-08-03",
                      40,
                      36,
                      0.429748,
                      8377
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-08-04",
                      49,
                      27,
                      0.359904,
                      7502
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-08-05",
                      37,
                      12,
                      0.129296,
                      9281
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-08-06",
                      33,
                      24,
                       0.277425,
                       8651
                     ],
                     [
                      "2020-08-07",
                      42,
                      12,
                      0.142163,
                      8441
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-08-08",
                      42,
                      24,
                      0.257428,
                      9323
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-08-09",
                      34,
                      32,
                      0.336559,
                      9508
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-08-10",
                      28,
                      16,
                      0.296846,
                      5390
                    ]
                  ],
                  "200": [
                    [
                      "date",
                      "subscribers",
                      "clicks",
                      "ctr",
                      "sent"
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-11",
                      0,
                      2,
                      0.78125,
                      256
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-12",
                      1,
                      0,
                      0,
                      239
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-13",
                      0,
                      1,
                      0.460829,
                      217
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-24",
                      0,
                      1,
                      0.684932,
                      146
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-14",
                      0,
                      0,
                      0,
                      261
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-27",
                      0,
                      1,
                      0.70922,
                      141
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-15",
                      0,
                      0,
                      0,
                      155
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-31",
                      0,
                      1,
                      0.694444,
                      144
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-16",
                      1,
                      0,
                      0,
                      135
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-08-04",
                      2,
                      1,
                      0.561798,
                      178
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-17",
                      0,
                      0,
                      0,
                      123
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-08-07",
                      1,
                      2,
                      0.873362,
                      229
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-18",
                      0,
                      0,
                      0,
                      134
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-08-10",
                      1,
                      2,
                      2.10526,
                      95
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-19",
                      0,
                      0,
                      0,
                      128
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-20",
                      0,
                      0,
                      0,
                      67
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-21",
                      1,
                      0,
                      0,
                      126
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-22",
                      2,
                      0,
                      0,
                      92
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-23",
                      0,
                      0,
                      0,
                      156
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-25",
                      2,
                      0,
                      0,
                      154
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-26",
                      0,
                      0,
                      0,
                      181
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-28",
                      1,
                      0,
                      0,
                      192
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-07-29",
                      1,
                      0,
                       0,
                       140
                     ],
                     [
                       "2020-07-30",
                      1,
                      0,
                      0,
                      136
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-08-01",
                      1,
                      0,
                      0,
                      159
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-08-02",
                      0,
                      0,
                      0,
                      154
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-08-03",
                      0,
                      0,
                      0,
                      137
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-08-05",
                      0,
                      0,
                      0,
                      149
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-08-06",
                      2,
                      0,
                      0,
                      209
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-08-08",
                      0,
                      0,
                      0,
                      215
                    ],
                    [
                      "2020-08-09",
                      0,
                      0,
                      0,
                      215
                    ]
                  ]
                };

               var arrChartItems = [];
               var chartDivMultiple = [];
               var materialChart = [];
               var dataChart = [];
    
    var count = ObjectLength(forGraph);
    var propertyName = Object.keys(forGraph);
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var idCreated=`chart_${i}`;
        var idProperty=propertyName[i];
        $('.report').prepend(`<h3>${idProperty}</h3><div id="${idCreated}">loading....</div>`);
        
    }; 
    var performanceStatusGraphHeading = Object.keys(forGraph); // only heading if

    // data seperation for every chart 
    var i = 0;
    for (var property in forGraph) {
    arrChartItems[i] = (forGraph[property]);
    i++;
    }
    
    var view= [];
    var materialChart = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var chartDivMultiple = [];
        
        dataChart[i] = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrChartItems[i]);
        
        view[i] = new google.visualization.DataView(dataChart[i]);
        
        var seriesColors = ['blue', 'red', 'orange','green'];
        
        chartDivMultiple[i] = document.getElementById('chart_' + i);
        
        materialChart[i] = new google.visualization.LineChart(chartDivMultiple[i]);
        
        var options = {
            width: '100%',
            height: 300,
            colors: seriesColors
        };
        
        var arrItems = [];
        
        materialChart[i].draw( view[i], options);

        $('#series').find(':checkbox').change(function () {
            var cols = [0];
            var colors = [];   
            $('#series').find(':checkbox:checked').each(function () {
                    console.log(this);
                var value = parseInt($(this).attr('value'));
                cols.push(value);
                colors.push(seriesColors[value - 1]);
                    console.log(value, 'colors: ', colors);
            });
        
              view.setColumns(cols);
            materialChart[i].draw(view[i], options);
        });

    
    }

    function ObjectLength(object) {
        var length = 0;
        for (var key in object) {
            if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                ++length;
            }
        }
        return length;
    };
   }
   </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2 /css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


   <ul id="series" style="list-style: none">
       <li><input type="checkbox" name="series" value="1" checked="true" />subscribers</li>
       <li><input type="checkbox" name="series" value="2" checked="true" />clicks</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="series" value="3" checked="true" />ctr</li>
       <li><input type="checkbox" name="series" value="4" checked="true" />sent</li>
   </ul>
 <div class="report"></div>
```

Comment: Based on your error message ... you are calling view.setColumns(cols);  but view is an array and you should be calling that something like view[i].setColumns(cols);

Comment: I used  view[i] but getting error like this " view[i].setColumns is not a function"